# How do I access the not-the-first elements of an array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, tail, cdr

Swift's `Array` has a `first` function which returns the first element of the array (or nil if the array is empty.)

Is there a built-in function that will return the remainder of the array without the first element?

Comment: Howzabout `removeAtIndex:`? Pop off the first item and you're done. Or take a slice `arr[1..<arr.count]`.

Comment: Unhelpful comment-less downvote is not helpful. @matt Does removeAtIndex modify the original array? `slice` might be what I'm looking for, but it's a bit awkward—it's not unreasonable to expect a new language with much-touted functional features to have this built in.

Comment: The docs answer those questions; you don't need to be asking me!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is one that might help you get what you are looking for:

```
func dropFirst<Seq : Sliceable>(s: Seq) -> Seq.SubSlice
```

Use like this:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 18, 9, 10]

let b = dropFirst(a) // [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 18, 9, 10]
```

Comment: In Swift 3.0, Array has its own `dropFirst` function, so simply: `let b = a.dropFirst()`

Answer (score 18):

Correct answer for **Swift 2.2, 3+**:

`let restOfArray = Array(array.dropFirst())`

Update for **Swift 3+**:

as **@leanne** pointed out in the comments below, it looks like this is now possible:

`let restOfArray = array.dropFirst()`

Comment: or: `let restOfArray = originalArray.dropFirst()`

Comment: It was not possible before,I'm glad that it's fixed! I'll update the answer later :)